# looking to add properties to objective C Realm class on the fly

Tags: ios, realm

I am looking to add properties to realm class that is defined in an external data source. Looking for advise on how to add properties on the fly. Goal is to make the REALM class representation flexible.

example:
`class MyClass:RLMObject` 
`@property var1`
`@property var2`

added property data source  = `@[@"var3",@"var4"]`

looking to read this property data source and enhance my class in run-time to be

`class MyClass:RLMObject`
`@property var1`
`@property var2`
`@property var3`
`@property var4`

Also, interested if there are other ways to achieve flexible data model persistence in REALM without updating the class in run-time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Brian from Realm here.

The current API is built on top of a dynamic API :-). We do plan to support this with a more public API. Until then it's possible to use the one used for migrations and the private API used by the Realm Browser: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/tools/RealmBrowser. But be aware that API will likely change!

Comment: Hi Brian - It appears the migration API requires an object to be already persisted in REALM and also the updated class to be pre-defined. I am looking to programmatically add properties ideally at a class level to create a modified class, followed by setting the property values of the modified class and then persist object in a REALM.  It would be great if you could post a sample code on how to achieve using migration API and Realm Browser (I am unable to figure out the specific class in Github where the private API resides)..thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry if my reply was too encouraging :-) We currently don't have a public (and supported) API that supports what you want. We are going to add that. So it may be wrong to encourage you to use the private, undocumented and _unsupported_ API for now. So you would unfortunately have to dig it out yourself and be prepared to change it once we make a public API. Sorry that I can't help more on this until it's available publicly.

Comment: Hi Brian - Any ideas on timeframe for a flexible data model API being available and any workarounds that could be suggested in the meantime..the scenario I have is a data model with about 6 attributes that can be pre-defined and another 2-6 attributes that would be driven from a data source at run-time.

Comment: Hi, Sorry we can't really give any estimates. But it's something that is getting pretty high on our list now. The best I can suggest is to create a [github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues) and track progress there.

Answer (score 0):

The Browser is a separate project in the same repo under tools, it's an app that can be used to look at Realm files. The editing-arrays branch of this app does some things dynamically, although it doesn't edit schemas during runtime. That is however something that will come to both the Browser and the bindings in the future.

To get an idea on how to use the existing dynamic functionality you should check out the Migration and Dynamic tests here:

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/Realm/Tests

EDIT: This was meant as a comment, not an answer!